# Assembly code, what does it do?

Tags: assembly, risc-v

I'm interested to know what this assembly code do knowing that X1 is full of zeroes.

```
ori  X2, X0, 0xFFF
slli X2, X2, 12
ori  X2, X2, 0xFFF
slli X2, X2, 8
ori  X2, X2, 0xFF
xor  X2, X2, X1
addi X2, X2, 1
and  X2, X2, X1
```

The problem is that I don't understand what 0xFFF and 0xFF are. How am I supposed to know their values at all?

Comment: This is not a very well posed question, as you do not give any context for the origin of this code.  Can someone figure it out?  Probably, but omitting such information is just needlessly wasteful of people's time.  Additionally, something you have to keep in mind any time you are looking at a disassembly is that it's entirely possible that what you are looking at is not code at all, but rather data being mistakenly disassembled as if it were code.

Comment: @awjlogan why did you remove the original asker's architecture tag from this question?

Comment: @ChrisStratton The question was really what does `0xFF` mean, rather than anything to do with a specific architecture. But, not a big edit, just came up in the queue :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These look like instructions for a RISC-V microprocessor.
https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf

- ori is the "OR Immediate" instruction.
- slli is a "Left Shift Logical Immediate" instruction.
- xor is an "Exclusive Or" instruction.
- addi is an "Add Immediate" Instruction.
- and is a "Bitwise AND instruction".

> The problem is that I can't understand what are those 0xFFF and 0xFF
> how am I supposed to know their values at all?

These are integer literal values written in hexadecimal.  The value shown **literally** is their value.  We can guess based on the fact that these are all *literal* type instructions that the numeric operands are literals rather than a memory address.

- 0xFF is 11111111 in binary or 255 in decimal.
- 0xFFF is 111111111111 in binary or 4095 in decimal.

Writing the numbers in hexadecimal improves the readability of the code.  Especially because the code contains several bit-wise instructions.

Note that the X0 register is a hardwired zero per page 109 of the "RISC-V User-Level ISA V2.2".

```
ORI  X2, X0, 0xFFF //X2 <= 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
SLLI X2, X2, 12    //X2 <= 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000
ORI  X2, X2, 0xFFF //X2 <= 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
SLLI X2, X2, 8     //X2 <= 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000
ORI  X2, X2, 0xFF  //X2 <= 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
XOR  X2, X2, X1    //X2 <= 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
                   //      since it was given that X1 is all 0s.
ADDI X2, X2, 1     //X2 <= 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
AND  X2, X2, X1    //X2 <= 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
                   // since X1 was all 0s, the AND operation would
                   // clear X2 no matter what its prior value.
```

Comment: how did you know that 0xFF isn't location in memory?

Comment: @MrCalc Because its and "OR Immediate" instruction.  An *immediate* type instruction always uses a literal rather than a memory address or another register value in the operation.  A common naming convention is that assembly instructions that end with the letter "I" operate on immediate (literal) values.

Comment: Curious that you couldn't have the first line be: `ORI  X2, X2, 0xFFF`. Is this undefined behavior (or just an outright error being thrown)? Or would that also work, but the original is just the more clear approach since X0 is always zero?

Comment: What I'm wondering is why someone would go through this six-instruction rigmarole when they could just do `xori x2, x2, -1`.

Comment: @user4574 in the first line, shouldn't all `????` be actually `0000` as per x0 is always 0?

Comment: Actually, I'm now practically sure that x2 should be all-ones after the first instruction, as "ANDI, ORI, XORI are logical operations that perform bitwise AND, OR, and XOR on register rs1 and the **sign-extended 12-bit immediate**", so 0xFFF would become 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: @Marandil I was unaware that the immediate for ORI was only 12-bits.  You are probably correct that it would fully sign extend out to 0xFFFFFFFF.  I will update to reflect that.

Comment: @zwol Why stop there? Make it `sub x2, x0, x1` and you've eliminated seven instructions. ...but I suspect the answer to both our objections is that it was obfuscated on purpose to make an exercise for a course about learning assembly.

Comment: @Marandil: Indeed, unlike MIPS (where bitwise boolean instructions zero-extend their 16-bit immediate, vs. others sign-extending), RISC-V always sign-extends immediates to avoid muxing in the decode logic.  So `ORI  X2, X0, 0xFFF` is not encodeable, and most RISC-V assemblers will reject it instead of stuffing that bit-pattern into an immediate. e.g. `clang -target riscv32` says: `rv.s:1:14: error: operand must be a symbol with %lo/%pcrel_lo/%tprel_lo modifier or an integer in the range [-2048, 2047]`  (after converting the register names to lower case). Some RISC-V simulators might only warn?

Answer (score 0):

If X1 were not 0, then this code would calculate 2^Y, with Y the index of the lowest significant bit of X1, and store it in X2. The first 6 lines are an unnecessarily complicated way to store the one's complement of X1 in X2, the 7th lines adds 1 to that, making X2 the two's complement of X1 (in other words the negation of X1 if X1 were a signed integer in the usual two's-complement-encoding) and the 8th line stores the bitwise logical AND of X2 and X1 in X2.

The bitwise logical AND of a signed integer in two's-complement-encoding and its own negation just happens to be 2^(the index of its least significant bit). I.e. if X1==7==0b111, the output would be 1==2^0 (because the 0th bit was set); if X1==8==0b1000, the output would be 8==2^3 (because the 0th to 2nd bit were not set, but the 3rd bit was); if X1==12=0b1100, the output would be 4==2^2.